# Stacking Reverse Draw 4's in UNO Show 'Em No Mercy?

Tags: uno, uno-show-em-no-mercy

So according to [this source](https://www.coololdgames.com/card-games/shedding/uno/show-em-no-mercy/) the new UNO Show'em No Mercy game allows for stacking Draw Cards.

Someone asked a question in the comments there and I have been wondering the same:

It seems clear to me that you are allowed to stack Draw 2, Draw 4, Wild Draw 6, and Wild Draw 10s. But can you stack a Reverse Draw 4 as well? And if so, would the reverse effect activate? Perhaps someone who owns the game and has access to the manual can chime in.

Answer (score 1):

“With just two players this card skips the other player and makes YOU draw 4 cards! You may use the stacking rule to send the penalty back to the other player.”

Meaning you must play a Draw 4 card or higher to avoid drawing 4 cards.